# ASP.Net Core WebApi Project creates an empty solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, server, backend, webapi

I am trying to create a ASP.Net Core WebAPI application, i installed every sdk and runtime i was told to.

I then go into Visual Studio and create the Project from the ProjectCreator.
What I end up with is an empty solution and a project in the specified directory that i cannot open, with the error message the Project cannot be opened because it couldnt find a fitting sdk
(btw, creating it with .netCore3.1)

Heres a list of my installed sdks/runtimes:

- .NET Core Runtime 2.1
- .NET Core Runtime 3.1
- .NET Core SDK 3.1.1
- .NET Core SDK 3.1.4
- .NET Runtime 5.0
- .NET SDK 5.0.2
- .NET SDK 5.0.3
- ASP.NET Core 3.1.17
- ASP.NET Core 5.0.8

[This is what my solution explorer looks like tho the csproj is correctly placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyRmf.png)

Whats seems to be the problem? Too many runtimes/sdk?
Are they overriding each other? Visual Studio cannot choose? I am baffled, this should work :/

[Edit1]
This is the guide I am following: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

[Edit2]
I found a command that lets you see every sdk and runtime the dotnet/cli can access/see

(dotnet --info)
[Looks like dotnet doesnt seem to find an sdk i installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyBXs.png)

[Edit3]
I tried to manually install the .net core SDK 3.1 binaries into the C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet folder, but to no avail, dotnet --info still doesnt recognize the SDK

[Edit4]
I got it working, I will post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Can you link to the guide that you are following?

Comment: Yes sure, i edited the question with the link, its the official microsoft docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I did:

1. I uninstalled my Visual Studio IDE with the Visual Studio Installer
2. I uninstalled every .NET (Core) SDK and .NET (Core) Runtime
3. I did a fresh Visual Studio install with only the components i really need


   After that I checked the dotnet --info command and there was it, 2 SDKs were installed. When I create the WebAPI Project now, the Solution Explorer has a project and I can finally see all files. This was weird. Thanks everyone tho!

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution. You should be able to accept it as the correct answer.